# Elasticsearch get the result count of the query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to get the total count returned, this the query :

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "#query#",
            "fuzziness": "AUTO",
            "default_operator": "#operator#",
            "fields": ["*", "barcode^5"]
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "object": "#filter#"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "id",
    "name",
    "code",
    "object",
    "icon",
    "application",
    "page",
    "link_id",
    "html_description",
    "acl_key",
    "access_control"
  ],
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    },
    "require_field_match": true
  }
}
```

why is the count in the json response is always 0 while I have documents actually returned ?
resp:
hits:
hits: Array(0)
length: 0
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
max_score: null
total: {value: 0, relation: 'eq'}
[[Prototype]]: Object
timed_out: false
took: 13
_shards: {total: 21, successful: 21, skipped: 0, failed: 0}
[[Prototype]]: Object
success: true
took: 13
total: 0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7N0L.png)

Comment: Which version are you running? What you're showing here is not the raw response you get from ES, there must be a layer in between that does some transformation, because the top-level elements should be `took`, `timed_out`, `_shard`, `hits` and the result count is in `hits.total.value`

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, the version is 7.10.
The response is : 
resp:
hits:
hits: Array(0)
length: 0
max_score: null
total: {value: 0, relation: 'eq'}
[[Prototype]]: Object
timed_out: false
took: 13
_shards: {total: 21, successful: 21, skipped: 0, failed: 0}
[[Prototype]]: Object
success: true
took: 13
total: 0

Comment: That means you have 0 hits, I'm not sure how you can have "documents actually returned"

Comment: Actually you're right, I have 0 hits, because a parameter was missing, now it is working ! Thank you so much !

Comment: There's no magic :-) Glad you figured out